# File missing in Google Cloud Storage on AppEngine after following instructions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I wrote a file to Google Cloud Storage using the instructions given here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview

The code runs and executes successfully, however, after logging into my Storage account, I don't see the newly written file in my bucket.

Any ideas as to why?

So this is the export code:

```
This is the code I am using:

        try {   
            // Get the file service
            FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

            /**
             * Set up properties of your new object
             * After finalizing objects, they are accessible
             * through Cloud Storage with the URL:
             * http://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket/my_object
             */
            GSFileOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder()
              .setBucket(bucket)
              .setKey(key)
              .setAcl("public-read");

            // Create your object
            AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService
                    .createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build());

            // Open a channel for writing
            boolean lockForWrite = false;
            FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(
                    writableFile, lockForWrite);

            // For this example, we write to the object using the
            // PrintWriter
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Channels.newWriter(
                    writeChannel, "UTF8"));

            Iterator<String> it = spRes.iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                out.println(it.next());
            }

            // Close without finalizing and save the file path for writing
            // later
            out.close();

            String path = writableFile.getFullPath();

            // Write more to the file in a separate request:
            writableFile = new AppEngineFile(path);

            // Lock the file because we intend to finalize it and
            // no one else should be able to edit it
            lockForWrite = true;
            writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(writableFile,
                    lockForWrite);

            // Now finalize
            writeChannel.closeFinally();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = "Failed to export";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Consider adding your actual code, how you executed the code, and how you configure the access control between GCS and App Engine.

Comment: Well on local enviornment this will be stored under **__BlobInfo__** entity.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you have not added the **email** of your application which you can find under **Application Setting** of your appengine application.

Then you need to add this email in the Team under [Google API Console](http://code.google.com/api/console) for Google Cloud Storage with **is Owner** privilege. Make sure you are also using the same bucket name which you created in Online Browser Tool for Cloud Storage in the ***UploadOptions***.

Comment: Might also want to add that if OP is running on the dev server, the files aren't actually uploaded.

Comment: I guess it's still not working. I added the email address of my Team under Google's API Console for Google Cloud Storage with "is Owner" as the privilege. I'm going to include a snapshot if I can up above.

Comment: I guess i dont have permission to post an image. I can always email the snapshot to you guys or post it somewhere.

Comment: You must be missing something as I already have one app running in a similar fashion. And please keep in mind that it won't run on local. If you want I can share my code as well.

Comment: Thanks Ankur. At this point I am not sure what I am a missing. I believe the code is not the issue and it's more like the setting of the Google Cloud Storage account...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had 2 different projects setup in the Google Cloud Console. I was updating the wrong project.

Works now.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As Ankur said, you have to deploy your code on appengine to write to Cloud Storage. Otherwise the files will only be stored on your local hard disk.