# How do I use getServingUrl for a file saved in Google Cloud Store?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using AppEngine (Java) and Google Cloud Storage. The file is saved by the app in the bucket (I've verified that it works). Here's how I'm trying to get a serving URL:

```
filePath = "/gs/"+BUCKET_NAME+"/"+filename;
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(filePath);
servingUrl = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl(options);
```

The error that I'm getting doesn't say much:

```
com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFailureException: 
at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.getServingUrl(ImagesServiceImpl.java:284)
```

The file path is correct (I've checked, and when it's not I get a "File not found" error).

The following leads to the same outcome:

```
BlobKey blobKey = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey(filePath);
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);
ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl(options);
```

I'm using the cloud storage (and not blobstore) because I'd like to be able to set the file and "folder" names, which doesn't seem to be possible when using blobstoreService.createUploadUrl.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is no problem with the code in the question. The file that is being saved in the GCS included some meta data in addition to the main content. So, I needed to extract the image from the payload using Apache Commons FileUpload:

```
file = new ServletFileUpload().getItemIterator(request).next().openStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the blobkey for serving images even if you are storing the blob in bucket. Below is code snippet which was working for me.

> With Blobstore

```
            BlobInfoFactory blobInfoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();
            BlobInfo info = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
            ImagesService services = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
            ServingUrlOptions serve = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);
            String imageUrl = services.getServingUrl(serve); // This will give u image URL
```

Also more details you can find in the three answers which I have already posted on stackoverflow

[upload a file using spring MultipartFile and google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421460/upload-a-file-using-spring-multipartfile-and-google-app-engine/23425398#23425398)

[File missing in Google Cloud Storage on AppEngine after following instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491337/file-missing-in-google-cloud-storage-on-appengine-after-following-instructions/15493270#15493270)

[How can I upload an thumbnail image (blob) at the same time as an Entity into a datastore in google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306790/how-can-i-upload-an-thumbnail-image-blob-at-the-same-time-as-an-entity-into-a/15309278#15309278)

> With GAE Bucket

```
UploadOptions uploadOptions = UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName(bucketName); // eg. mybucket
```

**The following will return you the URL for uploading your blob files to GAE Bucket. Here you need to upload your blob content or images.**

```
String uploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("http://xxx.appspot.com/imageupload", uploadOptions);
```

**Serving images using blobkey**

```
BlobInfoFactory blobInfoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();
BlobInfo info = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
ImagesService services = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
ServingUrlOptions serve = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);
String imageUrl = services.getServingUrl(serve);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works when I'm saving stuff in the blobstore, but not in the cloud store. Using blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey leads to the same  error.

Comment: @swhy this is a working code for me with my bucket. Also check the links I have shared, that contains more information about bucket permissions.

Comment: Thanks Ankur. This works, but it creates two copies, one in the blobstore, and one in the bucket. Isn't it possible to create a serving URL for something in the Cloud Storage. I'd like to be able to set the file and "folder" names, which doesn't seem to be possible when using createUploadUrl.